# Auto log in to different domain without entering username and password

Tags: asp.net, jsp, authentication

I am in a system which developed by Java EE, the link is inside a jsp page, like in this jsp page i have `<a href="http://www.differnet.com/a.aspx" target="_blank">Visit W3Schools</a>`, need to log in to  this aspx page in different domain without entering username and password. What should put in the target attribute?

Comment: It seems you are misunderstanding here. target attribute is not meant for what you have explained.

Comment: i know, if in the same domain, i can use it to go to different page wiithou login, but i have no idea how to do the auto login for the different domain

Answer (score 0):

In a different domain, pass username and password as query string and fetch this in the aspx page. In the page_load of aspx page, check the username and password with database and allow user accordingly.

Comment: but i am not allowed to touch the aspx page.

Comment: so u cannot allow user to log in without touching aspx.

Comment: sorry, actually it will go to the login page, how can i pass username and password to the login page

Comment: Do you have username & password stored in JSP Session ?